# Java: Remove child object from menu tree

Tags: java, recursion, challenge-response, quantitative

I have this UI object with below structure, i dont have control on how that list is populated, but i had to remove some child items meeting my condition, can anyone please suggest how i can do it (Language is Java)

Class definition

```
Class MenuItemObj {
          private string menuID
          private string menuType
          private string menuDescription
          private MenuItemObj[] children
}
```

so my finaly menu item will be in array, menuItemObj[], and each menuItemObj will look like this (not exact code)

MenuItemObj
menuID
menuDescription
children --> have to remove child from here based on condition
MenuItemObj
children
MenuItemObj[] --> have to remove child from here based on condition

```
     MenuItemObj
```

condition i have is, menuId and type, any idea how can i remove those child objects?

i tried below logic, but its getting removed from current list, but not in the final list

```
public static MenuItemObj[] removeChildMenu(MenuItemObj[] menuItemArr) {
     List newMenuItemList = menuItems.toList()
     for( aMenuitem : menuItemArr) {
        if(aMenuItem.Children != null) {
            removeChildMenu(aMenuitem.children)
        } else {
                 newMenuItemList.removeif(conditionToRemove)
   
 }    
 return newMenuItemList.toArray()
}
```

There is no error or anything but way I handle the array and list in this recursive calls seems not going as I intended. Any suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkIBR.png)

Please change condition c.getAge() < 50 according to requirement.

```
public static MenuItemObj removeChildMenu(MenuItemObj menuItem) {
    if (menuItem == null || (menuItem != null && menuItem.getChildren() == null)) {
        return menuItem;
    }
    menuItem.setChildren(Arrays.stream(menuItem.getChildren()).filter(c -> c.getAge() <= 50)
            .toArray(MenuItemObj[]::new));

    return menuItem;
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see a `getAge` method in the code of the posted question. I don't even see anything that would imply the existence of such a method. Perhaps you misunderstood the question?

Comment: Hi Abra, I understood the question but I had added that code as an example to filter like that you can use any method or variable to filter your result instead of age.
Hope, I am clear now.